# Possible values for Deezer user status and countries

Tags: api, deezer

Here

http://developers.deezer.com/api/user#infos

the documentation says that for each user, a "status" is provided, but it doesn't say what a status is and which are the possible status. I guess it is related to the subscription (0:free 1:premium 2:premium+). Can someone confirm?

The country reported is the one where the user subscribed to deezer or the one where the user is at that moment?

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that the user status is related to the subscription - 0:free 1:premium 2:premium+.

Regarding the country reported,

- for free users, it's the country where the user is located at the moment.
- for premium users, it's the country where they subscribed.

Comment: Ok for the status.
About the country: in my case, it doesn't work: I am a premium+ user, registered in Italy and the API says "Spain" (where I am at the moment).